# Sign change in LASSO and RIDGE of coefficients

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

I am estimating in total three models: Logistic regression without any penalization (as benchmark model), logistic regression with L1 penalization (LASSO) and with L2 penalization (RIDGE). Now i recognize that the coefficients compared to the benchmark model sometimes flip the sign. Is this a possible effect? - Up to now I only thought they could be zero (LASSO) or go towards zero (RIDGE).

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think anything in regularization prevents or prescribes sign changes in coefficients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods will drive your weights towards zero, but they do not differentiate between positive and negative values. Just look at the penalty values for two potential weights, for example -10 and 10:

L2: The penalty is w^2 for a weight w, and (-10)^2 = (10^2) = 100

L1: The penalty is |w| for a weight w, and |-10| = |10| = 10

So both terms will lower the values of your weights, but will not prevent them from being negative.

Comment: You are right. Didn't think about that. Thanks.